# Replaced belts and they still squeak

Tags: hyundai, belt, elantra

I replaced the 2 belts on my 2011 Hyundai Elantra.  Now when I put the heat on it makes a weird squealing noise.

**What is it?**

Answer (score 4):

**belt tension**

I would imagine that the belt is not tightened enough with the tensioner pulley.

When you turn on your heat on some cars the air conditioner pump button on the dash will default to on.  My son's Hyundai does this.  At that time when the pump engages, even though you have it set to heat, added tension is applied to the pulley that turns the air conditioner compressor.  The added work on the belt overcomes the friction coefficient of the belt on the crank pulley and you hear the loud 'squeal' sound.

You will need to loosen your tensioner pulley on that belt and add tension to it.

Your belt that run's across the AC compressor pulley also drives your alternator and power steering.  2009 to 2011 model years are all the same.

**Instructions on replacement and adding tension**

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwG1ZVXdgYM) explaining how to change the belt properly and add tension to it.

Best of luck.

Comment: DucatiKiller is almost certainly right, but there are a couple of other possibilities for belt noise. Pulley misalignment is a common cause. It can also be caused by a belt that's too wide, or by foreign material, such as rust on the pulley.